# Requirement(s) for consistency of Runga Kutta methods?

Tags: numerical-methods

I know that for the RK2 method to be consistent we must have $a + b = 1$ in the following equation

$$\begin{aligned} y_{i+1} &= y_i + h(ak_1 + bk_2)\\
  k_1 &= f(x_i, y_i)\\
  k_2 &= f(x_i + \alpha h, y_i + \beta hk_1)
\end{aligned}
$$

However, for the general $s$-stage Runge-Kutta method, what conditions must one have on the terms in the Butcher tableau in order to ensure consistency?

Comment: Are you interested in general explicit (as the given one is) RK-methods or in implicit ones?

Comment: I am interested in general explicit RK-methods, not implicit ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider the explicit RK-method 
\begin{align*}
  y_{n+1} &= y_n + h \sum_{i=1}^s b_ik_i\\
    k_i   &= f\left(x_n + c_ih, y_n + h \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}a_{ij}k_j\right)
\end{align*}
with Butcher tableau 
$$ \begin{array}{c|cccc}
    c_1 & 0 & \cdots &  0 & 0\\
    c_2 & a_{21} & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
     \vdots & & \vdots \\
     c_s & a_{s1} & \cdots & a_{s,s-1} & 0 \\ \hline
         & b_1 & \cdots & b_{s-1} & b_s
\end{array}
$$
This is constistent (just the same as in the $s=2$ case) iff $\sum_{i=1}^s b_i = 1$. To see this, just note that $k_i \to f(x_n, y_n)$ as $h \to 0$ and hence 
$$ 
  \sum_{i=1}^n b_i k_i \to \sum_{i=1}^n b_i f(x_n, y_n), \qquad h \to 0.
$$